# confd configuration with HashiCorp Vault KV v2

Tags: configuration, hashicorp-vault, toml, confd

I'm creating a Vault Dev Server with `sudo vault server -dev` and putting a simple KV v2 secret with:

```
vault kv put secret/database url=db.example.com
```

I wish [confd](http://www.confd.io/) pick that value whenever value is changed in KV store in Vault. But I'm getting the error:

```
FATAL template: env.tmpl:2:9: executing "env.tmpl" at <getv "database/url">: error calling getv: key does not exist: database/url
```

When I run:

```
sudo confd --onetime --log-level debug --backend vault --auth-type token --auth-token s.ossadqwsssssssafadsd --node http://127.0.0.1:8200 -prefix='/secret'
```

My `/etc/confd/templates/env.tmpl` is:

```
[myconfig]
url = {{ getv "database/url" }}
```

and `/etc/confd/conf.d/myconfig.toml` is

```
[template]
src = "env.tmpl"
dest = "env.conf"
keys = [
   "secret/database"
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

KV v2 has data in a [`/data` prefix](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/kv/kv-v2.html#read-secret-version). You need to change your path to be `getv "data/database/url"` in the config template or change prefix to `/secret/data` in the flag.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error while running:
`sudo confd -onetime -backend vault -node http://127.0.0.1:8200 -auth-type token -auth-token s.aaaaaasasaasasas -prefix /secret/data` with the same confid defined above. Also tried changing the path. Do you have any working example with KV v2?

Comment: I don't really use confd - I use consul-template. It's possible that confd isn't compatible with the v2 API. That's why it's v2 instead of v1